# Script fails on one account but runs fine on another

Tags: segmentation-fault, glibc, heap-corruption

I have a data management script which runs fine under one account but if i try to run the same script under a different account i get the following error

```
*** glibc detected *** /path/home/bin/cmrun.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid 

pointer: 0x00007f0ad8890e18 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x76126)[0x7f0ad7083126]
/path/home/bin/libr1fns.so(+0x6c249)[0x7f0ad8870249]
/path/home/bin/cmrun.out[0x401724]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f0ad702bcdd]
/path/home/bin/cmrun.out[0x400d59]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00406000 r-xp 00000000 08:40 3221229132                         /path/home/bin/cmrun.out
00605000-00606000 rw-p 00005000 08:40 3221229132                         /path/home/bin/cmrun.out
0109f000-010c1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f0ad58c6000-7f0ad58c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:40 3221233102                 /path/home/bin/libhebrew.so
7f0ad58c7000-7f0ad5ac6000 ---p 00001000 08:40 3221233102                 /path/home/bin/libhebrew.so
7f0ad5ac6000-7f0ad5ac7000 rw-p 00000000 08:40 3221233102                 /path/home/bin/libhebrew.so
7f0ad5ac7000-7f0ad5ac8000 r-xp 00000000 08:40 3221233118                 /path/home/bin/libntctx.so
7f0ad5ac8000-7f0ad5cc8000 ---p 00001000 08:40 3221233118                 /path/home/bin/libntctx.so
7f0ad5cc8000-7f0ad5cc9000 rw-p 00001000 08:40 3221233118                 /path/home/bin/libntctx.so
7f0ad5cc9000-7f0ad5cca000 r-xp 00000000 08:40 3221231814                 /path/home/bin/libfocini.so
7f0ad5cca000-7f0ad5ec9000 ---p 00001000 08:40 3221231814                 /path/home/bin/libfocini.so
7f0ad5ec9000-7f0ad5eca000 rw-p 00000000 08:40 3221231814                 /path/home/bin/libfocini.so
7f0ad5eca000-7f0ad5f30000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 647173                     /lib64/libfreebl3.so
7f0ad5f30000-7f0ad6130000 ---p 00066000 08:02 647173                     /lib64/libfreebl3.so
             /path/home/bin/libfocutl.so
7f0ad61b4000-7f0ad63b4000 ---p 0007e000 08:40 3221226358                 /path/home/bin/libfocutl.so
7f0ad63b4000-7f0ad63ba000 rw-p 0007e000 08:40 3221226358                 /path/home/bin/libfocutl.so
7f0ad63ba000-7f0ad63cb000 r-xp 00000000 08:40 3221226388                 /path/home/bin/libcbh.so
7f0ad63cb000-7f0ad65cb000 ---p 00011000 08:40 3221226388                 /path/home/bin/libcbh.so
7f0ad65cb000-7f0ad65cc000 rw-p 00011000 08:40 3221226388                 /path/home/bin/libcbh.so
7f0ad65cc000-7f0ad65cf000 r-xp 00000000 08:40 3221248291                 /path/home/bin/libnlssys.so
7f0ad65cf000-7f0ad67cf000 ---p 00003000 08:40 3221248291                 /path/home/bin/libnlssys.so
7f0ad67cf000-7f0ad67d0000 rw-p 00003000 08:40 3221248291                 /path/home/bin/libnlssys.so
7f0ad67d0000-7f0ad67d1000 r-xp 00000000 08:40 3221229138                 /path/home/bin/libmbx.so
7f0ad67d1000-7f0ad69d0000 ---p 00001000 08:40 3221229138                 /path/home/bin/libmbx.so
7f0ad69d0000-7f0ad69d1000 rw-p 00000000 08:40 3221229138                 /path/home/bin/libmbx.so
7f0ad69d1000-7f0ad69da000 r-xp 00000000 08:40 3221233092                 /path/home/bin/libkkdo.so
7f0ad69da000-7f0ad6bda000 ---p 00009000 08:40 3221233092                 /path/home/bin/libkkdo.so
7f0ad6bda000-7f0ad6bdb000 rw-p 00009000 08:40 3221233092                 /path/home/bin/libkkdo.so
7f0ad6bdb000-7f0ad6bf7000 r-xp 00000000 08:40 3221225794                 /path/home/bin/libutlh.so
7f0ad6bf7000-7f0ad6df6000 ---p 0001c000 08:40 3221225794                 /path/home/bin/libutlh.so
7f0ad6df6000-7f0ad6df7000 rw-p 0001b000 08:40 3221225794                 /path/home/bin/libutlh.so
7f0ad6df7000-7f0ad6e0d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 647569                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7f0ad6e0d000-7f0ad700c000 ---p 00016000 08:02 647569                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7f0ad700c000-7f0ad700d000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 647569                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7f0ad700d000-7f0ad7197000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 647181                     /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f0ad7197000-7f0ad7396000 ---p 0018a000 08:02 647181                     /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f0ad7396000-7f0ad739a000 r--p 00189000 08:02 647181                     /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f0ad739a000-7f0ad739b000 rw-p 0018d000 08:02 647181                     /lib64/libc-2.12.so
7f0ad739b000-7f0ad73a0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f0ad73a0000-7f0ad7423000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 647189                     /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7f0ad7423000-7f0ad7622000 ---p 00083000 08:02 647189                     /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7f0ad7622000-7f0ad7623000 r--p 00082000 08:02 647189                     /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7f0ad7623000-7f0ad7624000 rw-p 00083000 08:02 647189                     /lib64/libm-2.12.so
7f0ad7624000-7f0ad7712000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1574383                    /usr/local/GP-4.3.14.1/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7f0ad7712000-7f0ad7912000 ---p 000ee000 08:02 1574383                    /usr/local/GP-4.3.14.1/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7f0ad7912000-7f0ad7919000 r--p 000ee000 08:02 1574383                    /usr/local/GP-4.3.14.1/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7f0ad7919000-7f0ad791b000 rw-p 000f5000 08:02 1574383                    /usr/local/GP-4.3.14.1/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
7f0ad791b000-7f0ad7930000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f0ad7930000-7f0ad794d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 647224                     /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
7f0ad794d000-7f0ad7b4d000 ---p 0001d000 08:02 647224                     /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
7f0ad7b4d000-7f0ad7b51000 rw-p 0001d000 08:02 647224                     /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
7f0ad7b51000-7f0ad7b73000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 647220                     /lib64/libncurses.so.5.7
7f0ad7b73000-7f0ad7d72000 ---p 00022000 08:02 647220                     /lib64/libncurses.so.5.7
7f0ad7d72000-7f0ad7d73000 rw-p 00021000 08:02 647220                     /lib64/libncurses.so.5.7
7f0ad7d73000-7f0ad7d7a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 647185                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.12.soautomic_test.sh: line 7: 177923 Aborted                 (core dumped) /path/home/bin/cmrun.out s=LOOPBACK, u=srvadmin, p=10838247AF51CF49, r=test, Appname=adhoc, w=1
```

I am trying to understand why its failing on one account on the server but runs fine on the other. Is it permission issue?

Comment: No, there's a bug in the program. It's corrupting its memory somehow.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to understand why its failing on one account on the server but runs fine on the other.

You have a heap corruption issue, and heap corruption *is like that*: the same program may run today and crash tomorrow, or it may start crashing when the length of `$USER` or `$HOST` is different, or for any number of similar "unpredictable" environment changes.

> Is it permission issue?

No. Your best bet is to contact the developer of `cmrun.out` and have her/him run the program under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) (you can also do that yourself to confirm that there is heap corruption), or better yet under [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (that requires rebuilding of the executable).